# Is a $Diff(M)$-invariant smooth function with a connected domain a posteriori the action by an element of $Diff(M)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups, principal-bundles

I am following the proof of Lemma 2.11 in Moerdijk, Mircun, "Introduction to Foliations and Lie groupoids". There is a claim I don't understand: suppose $V$ is an open set in a smooth manifold $M$ and have a smooth function $f: V \rightarrow M$, such that for some *finite subgroup* $G \subset \operatorname{Diff}(M)$, $f(x) \in G \cdot x$ for any $x \in V$. Then on any connected component of the intersection of $V$ with the set of points which have no stabilizer under $G \setminus \{ \operatorname{id} \}$, $f$ must be the action of an element in $G \setminus \{ \operatorname{id} \}$ on that component.

From the way this claim is phrased, it makes me think that it is a special case of the more general claim:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ be a principal $G$-bundle where $E$ is connected. Suppose $f: E \rightarrow E$ is a continuous map satisfying $\pi \circ f = \pi$. Then $f$ is just the action of a $g \in G$. However, in this generality the claim seems false; for example we can just take the map $f$ defined on fibers as $f(h) = e$ where $e$ is the neutral element of $G$.

Comment: What does the notation $f(x)\in \operatorname{Diff}(M)(x)$ mean?

Comment: @JasonDeVito It means that for every $x \in M$ there exists a diffeomorphism $g_x$ of $M$ such that $f(x) = g_x (x)$.  Notation comes from seeing $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ as a group acting on $M$.

Comment: "The set of points which have no stabilizer under Diff()" is empty, so there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are right, I apologize, I meant no stabilizer under $\operatorname{Diff}(M) \setminus \{ \operatorname{id} \}$.

Comment: The set is still empty. The dimension 2 case is easiest to describe. For any coordinate chart $U \subset M$ with diffeomorphism $\psi : U \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\psi(x)=0$, one constructs $F \in \text{Diff}(M) \setminus \{\text{id}\}$ such that $F(x)=x$ as follows. First, $F \mid M-U$ is the identity. Also, $F\mid U$ is a nontrivial "twist" map of $U$, meaning $\psi F \psi^{-1}$ rotates the radius $r$ circle through an angle $\theta(r)$ where the smooth function $\theta : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ satisfies $\theta(r)=0$ for $0 \le r \le 1$ and $\theta(r)=2\pi$ for $2 \le r < \infty$.

Comment: I am sorry for being slow, but  I still don't understand the notation.  Presumably $x$ is a point in $V$, so $f(x)$ is some other point in $M$.  So, the notatoin $f(x)\in \operatorname{Diff}(M)(x)$ simply means that $f(x)$ is the image of $x$ under some diffeomorphism?  If, say, $M$ is connected, then this means saying $f(x)\in \operatorname{Diff}(M)(x)$ is equivalent to asserting that $f:V\rightarrow M$ is a set theoretic function (i.e., it doesn't even need to be continuous.)

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. When I transcribed, I had not realised how important was the condition of invariance under a finite subgroup of diffeomorphisms, not under the whole group.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you also for implying that diffeomorphism group acts transitively on connected manifolds, I did not know that.